# Need for a new template for Dresden Files RPG

Tags: dresden-files

One of my players has raised the question

"Will there ever be a need for a new template in the dresden files rpg?"

So far as I could tell there isn't anything that couldn't be expressed

or am I missing something?

Can someone come up with a creature that isn't covered ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In an interview with Jim Butcher (author) and Fred Hicks (writer and owner of Evil Hat Productions) on [The Walking Eye podcast](http://www.thewalkingeye.com/?p=973), they revealed that a new supplement Rumors from the Paranet is in the works.  Their description of it was that it brought The Dresden Files RPG up to post-Changes, and included information for including this into your game, including new templates and powers.  They don't give ETAs until they are sure they will hit the date, so there's no ETA currently.  But it is coming.

Other resources to confirm: from JimButcherOnline.com [(1)](http://www.jimbutcheronline.com/bb/index.php?topic=21548.0),[(2)](http://www.jimbutcheronline.com/bb/index.php?topic=1303.60) and [RPGGeek.com](http://rpggeek.com/thread/571088/new-dresden-files-rpg-supplement-coming).

As far as uncovered creatures, I couldn't tell you without spoilers, but there are other things in The Dresden Files that aren't currently covered.  You can fudge these things (and I have), but you run the danger of changing them when they come out, or ignoring the official rules.  But there is always the possibility of fudging the rules.

Personally, when making something that's not covered, I usually start out with the Emissary of Power template.

Answer (score 2):

No matter how flexible a template system is, it's always possible to add to it with more templates, unless the template system has a finite number of possibilities. Even then, someone  somewhere will want to make one that adds a new element to increase the possibilities.

The best example of this effect is in the proliferation of classes in Rolemaster, D20, and Palladium games.

And, looking at the templates in DFRPG, there is plenty of room for them to be expanded and varied.

So, yes, it's likely that eventually, additional templates will become useful.

And, based upon Wraith808's answer, it's apparent the design team is going to do more.

Answer (score 1):

The Dresden Files templates are really just lists of powers to give to specific creatures -- "White Court Vampires have Inhuman Toughness, keyed to their Feeding Dependency". In that sense, *none* of the templates are necessary -- you can just build characters a la carte.

If there are inexpressible characters, they will probably create new powers for them.